# Python Local/Remote File Manager & RSync Terminal User Interface (TUI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, ssh, curses

I have been working on a Python Curses terminal user interface for RSync for a little while now. I recently visited code review and recieved some help with cleaning up the code to make it more pythonic. I worked for a bit to break up classes, simplify functions, etc. Now, I'm returning to see if my code is more complicated than it needs to be. Since I'm learning while programing, I'm trying to achieve loose coupling and high cohesion where it makes sense, but am also well.. learning while programming. During this adventure it seems some areas have become more simple and more reusable however, some areas of the code I feel like I have to inject multiple variables or instances to make something work.

The main function of the code sets up some instances to create left and right file manager panels, then allows for tabbing between the panels.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import os
import curses
import curses.textpad
import curses.panel    
import constants as CONST
from pathlib import Path
from options_menu import OptionsMenu
from ssh import SSH
from window_manager import WinManager
from file_explorer import FileExplorer
from reset_window import ResetWindow
from menu_bar import MenuBar
from status_bar import StatusBar
from key_press import KeyPress
from display import Display


def prepare_curses():
    """Setup terminal for curses operations."""
    stdscr.erase()
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_CYAN)
    stdscr.bkgdset(curses.color_pair(3))


def end_curses():
    """Gracefully reset terminal to normal settings."""
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.endwin()
    os.system('reset')


class Main:
    """Main function handles high-level switching between windows and file menus."""
    def __init__(self, menu_bar, win_manager, file_explorers, status_bar):
        _menu_bar = menu_bar
        _win_manager = win_manager
        _file_explorers = file_explorers
        _status_bar = status_bar
        _current_panel = 0
        ready_to_exit = False
        while ready_to_exit is not True:
            _win_manager.upd_panel(_current_panel, _file_explorers[_current_panel].full_path)
            Display(_file_explorers[_current_panel])
            key_press = KeyPress(
                _file_explorers[_current_panel],
                _file_explorers[_current_panel].data,
                _file_explorers[_current_panel].position,
                )
            _file_explorers[_current_panel].scroll()
            self.call_menu(key_press, _menu_bar, left_file_explorer)
            _current_panel = self.switch_panels(key_press.tab_event, _current_panel, _status_bar)
            ready_to_exit = self.exit_main_loop(key_press.key)
            curses.doupdate()

    def exit_main_loop(self, event):
        if event == CONST.CONST_LET_Q_LWRCSE_KEY:
            return True

    def call_menu(self, key_press, _menu_bar, _left_file_explorer):
        _call_menu_event = key_press.menu_event
        _key_press = key_press.key
        ready_to_return = False
        if _call_menu_event is True:
            while ready_to_return is not True:
                _menu_bar(_key_press)
                Display(_menu_bar)
                _key_press = KeyPress(
                    _menu_bar,
                    _menu_bar.menu_item,
                    _menu_bar.position
                    )
                
                self.call_ssh(_key_press.selected_menu_item)
                _ssh_is_enabled = self.ssh_enabled()
                ready_to_return = self.return_to_main_loop(_key_press.key, _ssh_is_enabled)
            _menu_bar.close_menu()
            ResetWindow(_left_file_explorer)
        else:
            return _call_menu_event

    def update_all_views(self, _menu_bar, _file_explorers, _status_bar):
        _left_file_explorer = _file_explorers[0]
        _right_file_explorer = _file_explorers[1]
        _menu_bar.draw_menu_bar()
        ResetWindow(_left_file_explorer)
        ResetWindow(_right_file_explorer)
        _status_bar.refresh(1)
        curses.doupdate()

    def call_ssh(self, selected_menu_item):
        if selected_menu_item == 'ssh':
            ssh_object.start(win_manager, stdscr, None)

    def ssh_enabled(self):
        return ssh_object.is_enabled

    def return_to_main_loop(self,event,ssh_is_enabled):
        if event in (
            CONST.CONST_LET_F_LWRCSE_KEY,
            CONST.CONST_LET_O_LWRCSE_KEY,
            CONST.CONST_LET_Q_LWRCSE_KEY
            ) or ssh_is_enabled is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def switch_panels(self, tab_event, _current_panel, _status_bar):
        if tab_event is True:
            _current_panel = win_manager.set_active_panel(_current_panel)
            _status_bar.refresh(_current_panel)
            return _current_panel
        else:
            return _current_panel


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Setup curses and begin initializing various packages to draw the menubar,
    #left and right windows, statusbar, a ssh object for storage, a global options object
    #for storage and setup the file explorers.
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    screen_height, screen_width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    prepare_curses()
    menu_bar = MenuBar(stdscr)
    win_manager = WinManager(stdscr)
    left_win = win_manager.draw_left_win()
    right_win = win_manager.draw_right_win()
    ssh_object = SSH()
    left_file_explorer = FileExplorer(win_manager, left_win)
    right_file_explorer = FileExplorer(win_manager, right_win, ssh_object=ssh_object)
    file_explorers = [left_file_explorer, right_file_explorer]
    left_file_explorer.get_file_explorers(file_explorers)
    right_file_explorer.get_file_explorers(file_explorers)
    status_bar = StatusBar(stdscr)
    global_options = OptionsMenu(stdscr)
    main = Main(menu_bar, win_manager, file_explorers, status_bar)
    ssh_object.ssh_close()
    end_curses()
```

From here, the code relies heavily on the FileExplorer and KeyPress classes which I've also included below. The FileExplorer class is responsible for iterating over the files and folders in a given directory, parsing them and saving them in a dictionary. FileExplorer is also meant to do the same thing but for files over SSH, to ultimately allow the use of RSync from/to a remote system.

```
"""FileExplorer Class and ResetPath Class"""
import curses
import os
import stat
from ssh import SSH
from human_readable_size import human_readable_size
from window_manager import WinManager
from pop_ups import PopUpFileOpener
from pop_ups import PopUpCopyFile
from pathlib import Path

class ResetPath:
    """Used to reset the path to '/' when FileExplorer messses up"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = 0

    def error(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.errors += 1
        if self.errors == 2:
            self.obj.path = '/'
            self.errors = 0


class FileExplorer:
    """Work horse of the application

    Does the bulk of the work by taking a path and listing directorys/files within that
    path. Also prints the list of directorys/files and is responsible for navigating
    through those files. The ssh_explorer method is meant to closely mirror the explorer
    method but is modified for paramiko where appropriate.
    """
    #path = '/'
    paths = [None, None]
    prev_paths = ['/', '/']
    path_errors = ResetPath()
    def __init__(self, win_manager, window, path='/', ssh_object=None):
        self.ssh_obj = ssh_object
        self.win_manager = win_manager
        self.window = window
        self.screen_height, self.screen_width = self.win_manager.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        height, width = self.window.getmaxyx()
        start_y, start_x = self.window.getbegyx()
        self.ssh_path_depth = 0
        self.depth = 0
        self.height = height
        self.width = width - 2
        self.start_y = start_y + 1
        self.start_x = start_x + 1
        self.position = 0
        self.scroller = 0
        self.event = None
        self.ssh_path = None
        self.ssh_path_hist = ['/']
        self.path_info = list()
        
        self.draw_pad()
        self.explorer(path)
        self.menu()

    def explorer(self, path):
        self.path = path
        if isinstance(self.ssh_obj, SSH):
            if self.ssh_obj.is_enabled:
                self.use_ssh_explorer(path)
                return
        #cleaned_path = self.clean_path(path)               #setting up for future use
        _full_path = self.get_full_path(path)               #create full path
        path_obj = Path(_full_path)
        file_dir_list = self.walk_tree(path_obj)            #get files and folders from directory
        data_list = self.file_dir_iter(file_dir_list)       #parse files, identify if file is dir, get size
        data_list = self.sort_file_list(data_list)          #sort the list of files and folder
        data_list = self.create_list_index(data_list)       #add index
        data = self.list_to_dict(data_list)                 #convert list to index
        self.data = self.root_or_dot_dot(_full_path, data)  #determine if parent dir exists
        
    def ssh_explorer(self, ssh_path):
        self.next_ssh_path = self.get_full_path(ssh_path)
        ssh_files_folders_dir = self.ssh_obj.sftp.listdir(self.next_ssh_path)
        ssh_files_folders_attr = self.ssh_obj.sftp.listdir_attr(self.next_ssh_path)
        self.ssh_get_abs_path(self.next_ssh_path)
        data_list = self.ssh_parse_files(ssh_files_folders_dir, ssh_files_folders_attr)
        data_list = self.sort_file_list(data_list)
        data_list = self.create_list_index(data_list)
        self.data = self.list_to_dict(data_list)
        self.data = self.root_or_dot_dot(self.next_ssh_path, self.data)

    
    def ssh_parse_files(self, files_folders_dir, files_folders_attr):
        data_list = list()
        #item = 0
        for file_name, attr in zip(files_folders_dir, files_folders_attr):
            #is_dir = Path.is_dir()
            is_dir = stat.S_ISDIR(attr.st_mode)
            size = attr.st_size
            size = human_readable_size(size, suffix="B")
            if is_dir:
                is_dir = '/'
            else:
                is_dir = ''
            data_list.append([is_dir+file_name, size])
            #item += 1
        return data_list

    def file_dir_iter(self, files_dirs):
        """Requires list object"""
        data_list = list()
        for item in files_dirs:
            #_full_path = os.path.join(self.full_path, item)
            _full_path = Path(self.full_path, item)
            #is_dir = os.path.isdir(_full_path)
            is_dir = Path.is_dir(_full_path)
            size = os.path.getsize(_full_path)
            #size = Path.stat().st_size
            size = human_readable_size(size, suffix="B")
            if is_dir:
                #item = os.path.join(' ',item)
                item = '/' + item
                item = item.strip()
                # item = os.path.normpath(item).strip()
            else:
                item 
            data_list.append([item, size])
        return data_list

    def create_list_index(self, list):
        """Requires list object"""
        i = 1
        for item in list:
            item.insert(0,i)
            i = i + 1
        return list

    def use_ssh_explorer(self, path):
        if self.win_manager.active_panel == 1:
            self.right_file_explorer.ssh_explorer(path)

    def get_full_path(self, path):
        #self.depth_test = len(path.parts)
        if path == '/':
            self.path_info.append('/')
            self.depth = 0
        elif path == ('..'):
            if self.depth != 0:
                
                self.path_info.pop()
                self.depth -= 1
        else:
            self.path_info.append(path)
            self.depth += 1
        self.full_path = ''.join(map(str, self.path_info))
        return self.full_path.replace('//','/')

    def walk_tree(self, path):
        file_dir_list = list()
        for file_obj in path.iterdir():
            file_dir_list.append(file_obj.name)
        return file_dir_list

    def sort_file_list(self, list):
        """Requires list object"""
        data_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x:x[:1])
        return data_list

    def get_file_explorers(self, file_explorers):
        '''imports file explorers'''
        self.file_explorers = file_explorers
        self.left_file_explorer = file_explorers[0]
        self.right_file_explorer = file_explorers[1]

    def clean_path(self, path):
        return path.replace('//','/')

    def list_to_dict(self, data_list):
        item = 0
        data_dict = dict()
        data_dict = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in data_list}
        return data_dict

    def root_or_dot_dot(self, path, data):
        if path == '/':
            data[0] = ['/','']
        else:
            data[0] = ['..','']
        return data

    def join_path(self, path_1, path_2):
        return os.path.join(path_1,path_2)

    def draw_pad(self):
        '''draws pad larger than the file window so that it is scrollable'''
        self.pad = curses.newpad(self.height + 800, self.width) #size of pad
        self.pad.scrollok(True)
        self.pad.idlok(True)
        self.pad.keypad(True)
        self.pad.bkgd(curses.color_pair(1))

    def menu(self):
        '''creates selectable list of items, files, folders'''
        self.pad.erase()
        self.height, self.width = self.window.getmaxyx()
        self.screen_height, self.screen_width = self.win_manager.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        self.max_height = self.height -2
        self.bottom = self.max_height #+ len(self.tup) #self.max_height
        self.scroll_line = self.max_height - 3
        self.pad.setscrreg(0,self.max_height) #self.bottom -2)
        self.width = self.width - 2
        self.pad_refresh = lambda: self.pad.noutrefresh(
            self.scroller,
            0,
            self.start_y,
            self.start_x,
            self.bottom,
            self.screen_width - 2
            )
        #par = '[ ]' # can be added to the msg below to create a selector, likely to be removed
        for index, items in self.data.items():
            padding = self.width - len(items[0]) - 5
            if index == self.position:
                mode = curses.A_REVERSE
            else:
                mode = curses.A_NORMAL
            msg = f'{index:>3}{" "}{items[0]}{items[1]:>{padding}}'
            self.pad.addstr(index, 0, str(msg), mode)
            if mode == curses.A_REVERSE:
                self.cursor = self.pad.getyx()[0]
        self.pad_refresh()

    def set_paths(self, path):
        panel = WinManager.active_panel
        if panel == 0:
            oth_panel = 1
        else:
            oth_panel = 0
        if path is None:
            self.paths[panel] = self.prev_paths[panel].replace('//','/')
        else:
            self.prev_paths[panel] = self.paths[panel]
            self.paths[oth_panel] = self.prev_paths[oth_panel]

    def enter(self):
        """Changes the directory or opens file when enter key is called"""
        _selected_path = self.get_file_name()
        is_dir = _selected_path.startswith('/')

        if self.position != 0:
            _path_to_open = self.join_path(self.full_path,_selected_path)
            if is_dir:
                if WinManager.active_panel == 1:
                    if self.ssh_obj.is_enabled:
                        self.new_path =  self.path                    
                self.pad_refresh()
                self.position = self.scroller = 0
                self.paths[self.win_manager.active_panel] = _path_to_open
                self.set_paths(_path_to_open)
                self.explorer(_path_to_open)
            else:
                PopUpFileOpener(self.file_explorers, self.win_manager.stdscr, _path_to_open)
        else:
            path_parent = Path(self.full_path).parent

            if self.ssh_obj:
                    if self.ssh_obj.is_enabled and self.win_manager.active_panel == 1:
                        self.par_dir = '..'
            self.set_paths(self.full_path)
            self.explorer(_selected_path)

        self.win_manager.upd_panel(self.win_manager.active_panel, self.full_path)

    def ssh_explorer_attr(self):
        if glbl_opts.low_bandwidth:
            size = 0
        else:
            self.ssh_files_folders_attr = self.ssh_obj.sftp.listdir_attr(
                path=self.next_ssh_path)
            size_list = []
            for entry in self.ssh_files_folders_attr:
                size = entry.st_size
        return size_list

    def ssh_get_abs_path(self, path):
        self.ssh_abs_path = self.ssh_obj.sftp.normalize(path)

    def go_to_top(self):
        self.position = 0
        self.scroller = 0

    def go_to_bottom(self):
        data_length = len(self.data)
        self.position = data_length - 1
        self.scroller = data_length - self.scroll_line - 1

    def del_selected_items(self, sel_file):
        PopUpDelete(sel_file)

    def copy_selected_items(self):
        file_name = self.get_file_name()
        if self.position != 0:
            if self.win_manager.active_panel == 0:
                #self.from_file = self.path + '/' + file_name
                self.from_file = self.left_file_explorer.full_path + '/' + file_name
                self.to_path = self.right_file_explorer.full_path
            elif self.win_manager.active_panel == 1:
                self.from_file = self.right_file_explorer.full_path + '/' + file_name

                self.to_path = self.left_file_explorer.full_path
            PopUpCopyFile(
                self.file_explorers,
                self.win_manager.stdscr,
                self.from_file,
                self.to_path,
                file_name
                )

    def start_rsync(self):
        file_name = self.data[self.position][0]
        left_panel_path = left_file_explorer.abs_path
        right_panel_path = right_file_explorer.ssh_abs_path
        if self.win_manager.active_panel == 0:
            self.from_file = left_panel_path + '/' + file_name
            self.to_path = right_panel_path
        elif self.win_manager.active_panel == 1:
            self.from_file =  right_panel_path + '/' + file_name
            self.to_path = left_panel_path
        if self.position != 0:
            rsync_obj = RSync(0).start(self.from_file, self.to_path, file_name)
            
    def scroll(self):
        if self.cursor > self.scroll_line:
            self.data_length = len(self.data) - 1
            if self.position != self.data_length:
                self.scroller = self.position - self.scroll_line
        if self.scroller == -1:
            self.scroller = 0
        if self.position == 0:
            self.scroller = 0

    def get_file_name(self):
        return self.data[self.position][0]

    def is_dir(self, path):
        if path.startswith('/'):
            self.full_path = os.path.join(path, '')
            return True
        return False
```

Here is the KeyPress class. The KeyPress class is well responsible for awaiting a keypress and then either going up or down, left or right in a menu, or kicking off some function such as copying a file, creating a directory or starting rsync, if ssh'd into a remote system.

```
"""KeyPress Class"""
import curses
import constants as CONST
from pop_ups import PopUpNewDir
from navigate import navigate


class KeyPress:
    """Call function based on keypress

    This Class utilizes the curses module to evaluate a keypress (arrow keys, enter, escape, etc)
    and complete an action."""
    def __init__(self, obj, items=None, position=None):
        self.selected_menu_item = None
        self.obj = obj
        self.items = items
        self.tab_event = False
        self.menu_event = False
        self.position = position
        self.get_input(obj)
        self.key_or_arrow_event()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.selected_menu_item = None
        return self.key

    def get_input(self, obj):
        obj.window.keypad(True)
        try:
            self.key = obj.window.getch()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return

    def key_or_arrow_event(self):
        if self.key in (curses.KEY_LEFT, curses.KEY_RIGHT, curses.KEY_UP, curses.KEY_DOWN):
            self.arrow_event()
        else:
            self.key_event()
        
    def arrow_event(self):
        if self.key == curses.KEY_UP:
            self.obj.position = navigate(-1, self.items, self.position)
        elif self.key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            self.obj.position = navigate(1, self.items, self.position)
        elif self.key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            self.obj.position = navigate(1, self.items, self.position)
        elif self.key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            self.obj.position = navigate(-1, self.items, self.position)

    def key_event(self):
        event = self.key
        if event == CONST.CONST_ENTER_KEY:
            enter_key_event = self.enter_key()
            self.selected_menu_item = self.items[self.position]
            if enter_key_event is not None: #use this or selected_menu_item... test and delete one or other
                event = enter_key_event
            return event
        #elif event == 'ssh':
        #    return self.open_program(event)
        elif event == CONST.CONST_ESCAPE_KEY:
            return event
        elif event == CONST.CONST_TAB_KEY:
            self.tab_event = True
        elif event in (CONST.CONST_LET_F_LWRCSE_KEY, CONST.CONST_LET_O_LWRCSE_KEY):
            self.menu_event = True
        elif event == CONST.CONST_LET_Q_LWRCSE_KEY:
            return event
        elif event == CONST.CONST_LET_X_LWRCSE_KEY:
            self.close_ssh_key(event)
        elif event == CONST.CONST_NUM_5_KEY:
            self.copy_key()
        elif event == CONST.CONST_LET_N_LWRCSE_KEY:
            self.new_dir_key(obj, event)
        elif event == CONST.CONST_LET_B_LWRCSE_KEY:
            self.to_bottom_key(obj)
        elif event == CONST.CONST_LET_T_LWRCSE_KEY:
            self.to_top_key(obj)
        elif event == CONST.CONST_NUM_9_KEY:
            self.delete_key(obj, items, position)
        else:
            pass

    def to_top_key(obj):
        self.obj.go_to_top()

    def to_bottom_key(obj):
        self.obj.go_to_bottom()

    def delete_key(obj, items, position):
        item = items[position][0]
        self.obj.del_selected_items(obj._exp.path + '/' + item)

    def new_dir_key():
        PopUpNewDir()

    def enter_key(self):
        item = self.obj.enter()
        if item is not None:
            return item

    def close_ssh_key():
        if self.ssh_obj.is_enabled:
            self.ssh_obj.ssh.close()
            self.ssh_obj.enabled()
            win_manager.upd_panel()
            #right_file_explorer.explorer(right_file_explorer.path)
            #right_file_explorer.menu()
            #ResetWindow(right_file_explorer)
        else:
            pass

    def copy_key(self):
        self.obj.copy_selected_items()
```

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is making the code more transportable, more loosely coupled, but ultimately to help me learn so I can build good 'programming' habits and write better! I have the program up on github here with all of the classes https://github.com/1amdash/syncrpy-tui